# How to redirect submit button to next page if answer is correct

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to redirect submit button to next question url if answer is correct.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    Answer the question.
    </p>
    CLUE: The base is rotated
    <br/></body>

    <form action="" method="post">
    Answer: <input type="text" name="number" /><br />

    <input name="submit" type="submit">
    </form>

    </html>
```

Comment: `if($_POST['number'] == "answer") { echo "Correct"; // or header("Location: correct.php"); } else { die("Sorry"); }`

Comment: visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Do you want a JavaScript or PHP solution? Because the question has only the JS tag.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I want to redirect it to next page if answer is correct.

Comment: tymeJV edit my question and removed php tag.

Comment: Do you have the answer on client side?

Comment: No on server side @Kaf

Comment: @ManishSaini Use `header("Location: correct.php");` instead of echo I put in my comment.

Comment: @ManishSaini You may be better off using sessions in case someone tries to access `correct.php` directly. [See my answer below.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19364619/1415724) - tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of this placed before your html tag:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['number']) && $_POST['number'] == 12345) {
    header('Location: /next/page/');
}
?>
```

Comment: Its working but if i want to show an message if it is not correct i am using else but it showing the else message when page will appear.

        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['number']) && $_POST['number'] == 12345) {
        header('Location: 2.html');
        }
        else  
        { wrong("You are wrong"); }
        ?>

Answer (score 0):

Since it's going back to the same page, you could add a hidden input field.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST[number]){

        if ($_POST['number'] == $answer){
            $_SESSION['answer1'] == $answer;
            header("Location: /next/page");
        }
    }

?>
```

Save it as a session variable so you can easily have access to them at the end of the quiz or whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hidden field containing the answer, and create a new script that checks the answer in the text field to the answer in the hidden field ($answer) and redirects to a new page.

Let's say we call this script checkanswer.php -> then your form action should read `<form action="checkanswer.php" method="post">`

checkanswer.php would then look like:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['number'])
    {
     if ($_POST['number'] == $answer)
       { echo "Correct!";
         header("location:nextquestion.php");
       }
         else
         { echo "That is not the right answer, try again!"; }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic method to check if the correct answer was given, and using `header` to redirect to another page.

If a user types the word `answer` in your form field, then it will be set as `TRUE`.

If the answer is incorrect, it will show `Sorry, wrong answer.`

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$answer = "answer";

if($_POST['number'] == $answer) {

// echo "Correct"; 

header("Location: correct.php"); 

} else { 
die("Sorry, wrong answer.");
}

}

?>
```

### Using sessions method:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
$_SESSION['name'] = "correct";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$answer = "answer";

if($_POST['number'] == $answer) {
header("Location: correct.php"); 
} else { 
die("Sorry, wrong answer");
}

}

else {
die("You cannot access this page from here.");
}
?>
```

### correct.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
die("Sorry, session not set.");
}

else {
echo "Correct answer.";
}

?>
```